# Problem using Stateful EJB in ManagedBean with RequestScope

Tags: session, jsf-2, ejb-3.1

I'm using JSF 2.0 and EJB 3.1 in the Glassfish v3 app server. And I'm facing actually the follwing problem:
In a MenagedBean with RequestScope I want to access a session object (an EJB with @Stateful) which should store some session relevant information as the seleced category, the seleced page (with a datatable paginator for each category), etc. - nothing special I think.
The first time a category is selected, the datatable is created and displayed. Allright so far.
Now, if an item (row) is clicked (to show the item's details) or if the next page should be displayed, the session (the stateful EJB) is recreated and again the default values are used to display and render the page.

The code looks like:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TableViewBean {

    @EJB
    SessionBean session;

    public DataModel getTable() {
            return session.getDataModel();
         }

        public SessionBean getSession(){
            return session;
        }
         public void next() {
             session.getPaginator().nextPage();
             session.resetList();
         }

         public void previous() {
                session.getPaginator().previousPage();
                session.resetList();
         }
         // some other code
    }
```

and the session EJB:

```
@Stateful
public class SessionBean {

private String selectedType = "Entity";

private DataModel dataModel;
private int rowsPerPage = 5;
private Paginator paginator;


public void setSelectedType(String type){
    if(!type.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedType)){
        selectedType = type;

        updateService();
    }
    resetList();
}


public void resetList() {
    dataModel = null;
}

public void resetPagination() {
    paginator = null;
}

public int getRowsPerPage() {
    return rowsPerPage;
}

public void setRowsPerPage(int rowsPerPage) {
    this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
    resetList();
    resetPagination();
}

public Paginator getPaginator() {
    if (paginator == null) {
        paginator = new Paginator(rowsPerPage) {

            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return selectedService.getCount();
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                DataModel model = null;
                if(selectedService != null){
                    model = new ListDataModel(....);
                }
                return model;
            }
        };
    }

    return paginator;

}

public DataModel getDataModel() {
    if(dataModel == null){
        dataModel = getPaginator().createPageDataModel();
    }

    return dataModel;
}
```

}

If  I change the Scope of the ManagedBean to SessionScope everything works fine, but I don't like this, because of use of memory concerns.

What's wrong with my code...please help me.

Greetz, Gerry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your RequestScoped ManagedBean is re-instantiated for each request (that's what RequestScoped means after all). Therefore, with each instantiation it gets injected with a **new** SFSB instance.

Comment: Okay, but how can I manage my requirement to use a requestScope Managedbean as the backingbean and to have a session-long EJB which maintains all session related stuff and can be used in different backing beans?

Comment: Why is the request scope managed bean a requirement again ? Due to memory concerns ? But your managed bean only holds a reference to a stateful bean (which is mandatory, if you want to make use of that bean as stateful). Your memory concerns, if any, could refer to the stateful bean itself, not to the really lightweight managed bean.

Comment: However, if this really is a requirement, you can achieve the desired behaviour; but you need to store the SFSB in your HttpSession somehow and then look it up in your managed bean's getTable() method, instead of injecting it as instance field.

Comment: Now, I'm completely confused. Again, I want to have some backing beans (one sperate per page) with requestScope and only one session-long EJB (stateful bean). So my idea was to inject this EJB in every ManagedBean via @EJB but that doesn't work (realting to your first answer).

Comment: So, the only chance is to store this session EJB in the HTTPSession? - Then how does the statement in one of my books fit to your and my experiance: "Stateful: This type of bean maintains state and is associated with a specific client. It is
useful for tasks that have to be done in several steps." And that is exectly the feature I need... how does it work?

Comment: Since the SFSB _instance_ "is associated with a specific client", if your client (the managed bean) gets lost and an other one takes its place for the next request, the new one doesn't have any SFSB associated with it (until a new one gets injected). So the SFSB does maintain state and all, but the client does not survive for more than one request in order to make use of it. You need to associate your bean with a client that is able to live longer.

Comment: I see! I've misunderstood the term "client" here. I was thinking of a client like a webbrowser, etc. The point of view, that the ManagedBean could be a client for the Stateful bean didn't come to my mind. Thanks a lot!